# Interesting question about full rank of random matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question about rank of a random binary matrix. Assume that I have to make a random binary matrix with its size are k rows and n colmuns (k<=n). Each columns only has 1 or 0 values. Now I want to caculate the probability that the binary matrix is full rank (k). Please help me formula it. Note that 0 and 1 is created with same probability.
This maybe one solution. However, I don't know it is whether correct or not. Let us verify it

[image]

Comment: And your reasoning for the formula is...?

Comment: I just think it

Comment: On what basis?.

Comment: Is the matrix considered to be over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, or over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is matrix in $Z_2$, that mean has only values is $0$ or $1$

Comment: But in $Z_2$ $1+1=0$ and in $\Bbb R$ $1+1\ne 0$.

Comment: Let assume it is coin

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula gives probability zero for a square matrix $k=n$:
$$1-2^{k-n}=1-2^0=0.$$
It is possible?

Comment: maybe my answer is wrong. Do you have other answer?

Comment: @mjohn1282, yors answer *is* wrong. Check several small cases by brute force and try to guess a formula. I think that the general case can be deduced from  the square case easily.